# WP Pagination for listing child pages

Tags: pagination, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress, and have used this http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-display-excerpts-of-child-pages-with-a-shortcode/ to make a short tag to list child pages on parent page.

However, I need to add a pagination into this, to list only 9 recent child pages on this page where I have short tag.

Any idea how to do it? Or some other idea to replace this with something that can support pagination to list child pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination doesn't work for Pages in Wordpress. Pages are not to be meant by paginated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `$args` to have a limit using `posts_per_page`.

```
    $args = array(  
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,  
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 9
);
```

To get pagination working, I recommend [Simple Pagination](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-pagination/). Once installed, call this where you would like it to appear like so:

```
<?php if(function_exists('wp_simple_pagination')) {
    wp_simple_pagination();
} ?>
```

Comment: this plugin allows pagination for posts & comments but not pages... Are you sure it will work?

Comment: Pagination for pages? Okay, well that would need something entirely different. Personally, pages are not meant to be 'paged', they are a entirely different entity to posts. Why would you want to page them, they should be dealt with in a menu.

Comment: hmm... i know that but I need that for some reason :(